# Can pseudo-elements be used alone in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

According to W3C, the definition of a selector does not cover a pseudo-element:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selector-syntax

The above link says:

> A selector is a chain of one or more sequences of simple selectors
>   separated by combinators.

and it also says:

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector,
>   attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

Regarding how a pseudo-element should be used, it says:

> One pseudo-element may be appended to the last sequence of simple
>   selectors in a selector.

and

> Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector, and if present it
>   must appear after the sequence of simple selectors that represents the
>   subjects of the selector.

So does that mean that a pseudo-element can only be a suffix to a "valid" selector and should not be used alone?

Comment: Selectors 4 *somewhat* clarifies this by making "selector" a truly abstract term that can be applied to any part or combination of parts of selector(s), and replacing Selectors 3's definition with "complex selector" (and "sequence of simple selectors" becomes "compound selector"). Even so, it remains debatable even within the CSSWG whether a pseudo-element should be considered part of a complex selector (the current wording of selectors-4 strongly implies that it is not).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does that mean that a pseudo-element can only be a suffix to a "valid"
>   selector and should not be used alone?

Your conclusion is not true, because the [universal selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector) `*` can be omitted.

> If a universal selector represented by `*` [...] is immediately
>   followed by a [pseudo-element](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements), then the `*` may be omitted and the
>   universal selector's presence implied.

So you can use a pseudo-element alone, e.g. `::before`, because under the hood it will be treated like `*::before`.

```css
::before {
  content: 'Hello!';
}
```